# Mysql is nuul password has been encrypted

Tags: mysql

mysql has been encrypted 
How do you decode it again?
I do not know the key value
And it was all returned as null.

Answer (score 0):

If it is encrypted you can not obtain the data without the encryption key, that is the whole point of encryption.